# How to fix: Could not find method namespace() error

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-studio

I wanted to run my FLUTTER application on an Android phone, but every time I get a new error. It works fine on the web browser, but the error appears when I try to run it either on a phone connected via USB or an Android emulator.

this is the error:

```
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\CW\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\flutter_local_notifications-16.3.0\android\build.gradle' line: ??

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':flutter_local_notifications'.
> Could not find method namespace() for arguments [com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications] on extension 'android' of type com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\src\main\groovy\flutter.groovy' line: ???

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':flutter_local_notifications'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Cannot invoke method substring() on null object
   > compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================
```

and this is the "build.gradle" file:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.ecommerce01"
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Please help me to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It is looks like you missed steps that are required for flutter_local_notifications on Android.
More info [here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications#-android-setup)